# Faster way to modify a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array with 4 million rows and 4 columns (shape = (4000000,4))

I need to modify/ decrease the number of rows, based on the value in fourth column.
For example few of my rows in my data set look like the following:

```
a = np.array([[1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 0],[1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 0],[1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 1],[1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 1],[1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 0]]);
```

My result should be the following (only rows with last column value = 1)

```
b = [1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 1],[1.32, 24.42, 224.21312, 1]
```

A for loop to go through each row is taking a long time to process.

I have 200 of these arrays, so I am already using multiprocessing for each array.

Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
a[a[:,3] == 1]
```

gives:

```
array([[  1.32   ,  24.42   , 224.21312,   1.     ],
       [  1.32   ,  24.42   , 224.21312,   1.     ]])
```

Comment: `a[a[:, -1] == 1]` is slightly better for `n` length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to `dataframe` and operate your operations there and then convert back to array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df[df[3] == 1]
a = df.as_matrix()
```

Output:

```
array([[  1.32   ,  24.42   , 224.21312,   1.     ],
       [  1.32   ,  24.42   , 224.21312,   1.     ]])
```

Comment: You haven't really converted anything because it's still a numpy array underneath, this just wraps it in the overhead of pandas. You can operate on the array directly as shown in the other answer.